# Has any one tested Sitecore 8.2 compatibility with Solr 7.2?

Tags: solr

Currently, we are using `Solr 6.5`. We want to upgrade `Solr 6.5` to `Solr 7.2` to leverage bidirectional replication.

But Sitecore has not tested `Sitecore 8.2` - `Solr 7.2` compatibility. Also, there is no information available for same in Solr compatibility table(https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897)

Has anyone tried it?

Comment: "Has anyone tried it" is not really a good fit for this site. Consider instead asking about specific steps needed to install and configure it, or list out what you've tried to far and what problems you've run into. If you want a discussion before even starting, I suggest you come to Sitecore Slack instead.

Comment: Don`t do it. Just follow compatibility versions. I experimented with sitecore 9.0 + solr 7.2.1 and had a headache with solving issues by manually config changes.

Comment: It works I tried it, you need to change schema.config file accordingly and few issues for getting right indexes created which is painful process. I agree with everyone above, don't do this use Solr compatibility table for right Solr version